# Почему получаю ошибку при передаче параметра?

Tags: swift

Смотрю урок по свифту и вот там показывают такой пример

```
func sayHi() -> String{
 return "hi"
}

func doSmth(smth : () -> (String)){
 print(smth)
}

doSmth(smth: sayHi())
```

и все работает, но когда я пишу тоже самое у себя получаю вот такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я так понимаю что у меня более поздняя версия свифта чем используется в примере, но как тогда предать функцию как параметр?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пофиксил:)

```
func sayHi() -> String{
 return "hi"
}

func doSmth(smth : () -> (String)){
 print(smth())
}

doSmth(smth: sayHi)
```

похоже, Вы просто не в том месте поставили скобки.

Если детальнее - doSmth ожидает получить функцию, а добавив скобки, вы передаете ей результат выполнения функции. Собственно на это компилятор и ругается - он не может конвертировать строку (ту, которую возвращает sayHi) в функцию вида '() -> (String)', которую хочет doSmth.

Внутри функции doSmth smth - это функция и ее нужно вызвать. Для этого там и нужны скобки.

Comment: Ну вроде похоже что так и есть хотя странно. Это же функция значит и вызываться она должна `says()` со скобками... а то как можно понять функция это или значение `doSmth(smth: sayHi)` вот как по этой строке вы скажете передаю я как параметр функцию или значение? И второе тоже странно в функции `doSmth()` передаем как параметр `smth`  без скобок, а когда вызываем `print(smth())` уже со скобками... Почему? И при чем если скобки не поставить то получаю в логе вместо `hi` , `(Function)` что означает это?

Comment: Это все - так называемые функции высшего порядка. Проще говоря, когда тип переменной может быть функция, а значением - конкретная функция. Если передавать функцию просто по имени (без скобок), то функция не вызывается, а просто передается ее адрес с метаинформацией (но ее может и не быть, компилятор может и выбросить).  `doSmth(smth: sayHi)` - это передается функция, не вызывая ее (в с/с++ передали бы просто указатель). `print(smth())` - выполнить функцию и распечатать ее значение.  `print(smth)` распечатать значение переменной smth. Но адрес оно не печатает (жалеет Вас).

Comment: Кажется я понял) Спасибо!